# DataGridView: DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells doesn't honor header cells

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, formatting

All my columns, except the last one, are set to `DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells`. The last is set to `.Fill`.

However, when the grid is displayed, 2 of the non-last columns have header cells that wrap - their contents are wider than the contents of the non-header cells below.

Any ideas why the widths of the header cells aren't being taken into account by the column autosizing?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Visual Basic...

Comment: There are a bunch of options for this: maybe try DisplayedCells instead of AllCells. You can find all the options here: [DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewautosizecolumnmode.aspx)

Comment: I've tried all the options. Also calling the explicit resize columns after filling in the grid values in the 'Shown' callback.  Nothing so far affects it.

Comment: You are going to have to post your code that is having the problem, so we can find out why it is not working.